# JPA Query error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I added this query to my room repository, I started getting an error when booting the Spring application. If I comment the query the error disapears and the application boots correctly.

```
public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<Room, Long> {

    @Query("select Room r from Room join r.bookings b where not ((b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.beginDate <= :endtDate) or (b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.endDate <= :endDate) or (b.beginDate <= :initDate and b.endDate >= :endDate) and b.approved = true and r.roomType = :roomType)")
    List<Room> findWithDates(@Param("initDate") Date initDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate, @Param("roomType") long roomType);
}
```

The error:

```
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findWithDates found for type Room!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findWithDates found for type Room!
```

The room class:

```
@Entity
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="roomType_id" )
    private RoomType roomType;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="room", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();

}
```

Comment: Your `@Query` annotation - is it an `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`?

Comment: What versions of Spring and Spring Data JPA are you using?  Your code works for me with Spring v4.0.9 and Spring Data JPA v1.8.1.  You can find my sample code on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/33708655).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "select Room r from Room join r.bookings b where not ((b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.beginDate <= :endtDate) or (b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.endDate <= :endDate) or (b.beginDate <= :initDate and b.endDate >= :endDate) and b.approved = true and r.roomType = :roomType)", nativeQuery=true)
```

this worked, the query annotation was also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name clashes with methods automatically implemented by Spring (in your case Spring looks for a field called "initDateEndDateRoomType" and fails.

> The query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository infrastructure is useful for building constraining queries over entities of the repository. The mechanism strips the prefixes find…By, read…By, query…By, count…By, and get…By from the method and starts parsing the rest of it.

It should work however if you also extend `JpaRepository<Room, Long>`, but I haven't verified that.

Comment: Please let your interface extend `JpaRepository<Room, Long>`, it should work then (it seems that the annotation is ignored if you don't extend JpaRepository).